# Populating a listbox with previously filtered data

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, autofilter

I'm trying to populate a listbox with information from a filtered data.

The display only shows the first row filtered.

I tried `specialcells(xlcelltypevisible)`.

Here's some code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim Rang1 As Range
Dim LastCell As Long
Dim LastCell1 As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Rang  As Range
Dim MyArr As Variant

Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Define last row
    With WS
        LastCell = .Range("A" & Sheets("Mt-Gral").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'Define filtering range
    Set Rang = WS.Range("A2:Q" & LastCell)

    'Filter
    WS.Activate

    Rang.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="<>Closed"
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>Production"
    Set Rang1 = Rang.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    MyArr = Rang1

    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 8
        .ColumnWidths = "80pt;80pt;40pt;60pt;60pt;60pt;60pt;150pt"
        .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectExtended
        .List = (MyArr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add all visible cells in a range to an array like that, it will stop at the first time a cell is skipped, because you can only assign one range to an array at a time, and technically you are adding multiple ranges (since you skip cells).

To get around this, you can run a `for each` on your filtered range, and add all visible cells to your array separately. Something like this:

```
Sub listbox()
Dim i       As Long, lastr As Long, j As Long
Dim cel     As Range
Dim Myarr() As Variant
Dim rang    As Range

lastr = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rang = Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & lastr)

ReDim Myarr(0 To 17, 0 To lastr)
For Each cel In rang

    If Not cel.Rows.Hidden Then
        For j = 0 To 17
            Myarr(j, i) = cel.Offset(0, j)
        Next j
        i = i + 1
    End If

Next cel
ReDim Preserve Myarr(0 To 17, 0 To i - 1)

With Sheet1.ListBox1
    .Column = Myarr
End With

End Sub
```

*Edit:* as per T.M.'s suggestions I've switched how the array is assigned, adapted the `Redim` statement to match, and assign it to the listbox with the `.column` property. This gets rid of any excess rows towards the end.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the fast response, it actually worked but i need to put each record in a single row in my listbox. Your solution does put the filtered data in the listbox but puts each cell of each record in different rows. Thank you so much!

Comment: Friendly hint: OP requests a 2-dim array (i.e. `Range("A2:Q" & lastRow)`). - Further notes: 1) I'd avoid repetitive `ReDim Preserve` within the loop. 
Just dimension the array to the maximum row index before and execute a 
`ReDim Preserve Myarr(0 To i - 1)` outside the loop in a second step. 
2) Looping through a range by means of VBA is time consuming; suggest to 
assign the entire range including empty rows to a temporary array and to 
loop through this one instead skipping the empty items :-)

Comment: @emcalleja_ You are correct, you needed up to column Q on your line. I've updated my answer which will add all that is required to your array. I took @T.M. comments to heart as well, however struggled with the final `redim preserve` as it throws a "Subscript out of range" whatever I do. Perhaps any suggestion on how to implement?

Comment: @T.M. Never mind, got there eventually. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @Plutian - Sorry, forgot that you changed to a 2-dim array, as a `ReDim` only can change the **last** *array dimension*, i.e. the 2nd one in the post above. A work around could be to interchange rows/columns, to redim and eventually transpose the resulting array (caveat: possible limitation to 65K of rows in versions before Office 2019? when transposing)

Comment: @T.M. Yeah I realised my `unbound array` just returns the same array on my way home just now. Perhaps a pre-counter could work to see how many rows you need. I've no access to a PC until tomorrow so can't update my answer.

Comment: @Plutian - Suggest the following steps: 
a) Interchange row/column arguments by a first `ReDim Myarr(0 To 17, 0 To lastr)`, 
b) assign `Myarr(j, i) = cel.Offset(0,j)` within the inner `For`- `Next` loop,
c) execute a `ReDim Preserve Myarr(0 To 17, 0 to i -1)` outside the outer `cel` loop and
d) assign the array using the listbox'es **`.Column`** *property* via `.Column = Myarr` 
*(thus **avoiding** a `Application.Transpose` plus later assignment to `.List = Myarr`)*

Comment: @T.M. Thank you for the suggestions, the code has been adapted. Nice trick with the `.Column` assignment, I would've never thought of that. @emcalleja_ the now posted answer should work perfectly for your needs.

Comment: @Plutian - you are welcome; BTW edited your post replacing integer declarations to `Long` (`lastrow` could be higher than ~65K); fully qualified range assignment `Set rang = Sheet1.Range(…)`; `i = 0` is redundant as default value after declaration equals Zero.